# Run teamcity from failed step

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have 10 steps in build.

Often build fails at step 10 where it try to deploy rpm to artifactory.

Next time build again starts from 1 , can i configure build to start from 10step only if failed at that step.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in way to restart from a build step. You should rather breakup your single build configuration into multiple build configurations and setup dependency/build chains.

Comment: This is the preferred way. Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

The other way to achieve this is to manually disable first n steps that you want to skip. In your particular scenario it is rather tedious to disable 1-9 steps and then after the build enable them again but if you need to do that for a couple on steps once in a while it might be acceptable.

Comment: This will probably not work in case you have a dependency on former steps.